# How can I use Hilt in a Jetpack Compose app when it has no Application?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

Hilt is recommended when writing a Jetpack Compose app. The [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#application-class) say:

> All apps that use Hilt must contain an Application class that is annotated with @HiltAndroidApp

and AIUI the Application then acts as a root for all injectables. But my app doesn't have an instance of Application in its source code, only a MainActivity derived from ComponentActivity. What am I supposed to do? Just ignore that part and hope that annotating MainActivity with @AndroidEntryPoint will work because of some secret magic that Compose and Hilt do? Annotate MainActivity with something else (but what)? Somehow add an Application to my app even though the only documentation on doing so is '...'?

Comment: Create your own MyApplication class that inherits from Application and reference it in the manifest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the comment, just add a file for your app like this:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp: Application() {
}
```

And then add it to your manifest like this:

```
android:name=".MyApp"
```

Then in your MainActivity, just add your @AndroidEntryPoint.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {}
```